# Proving the correctness of an embedded complex sequence

Tags: calculus, analysis

A sequence of $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $ \mathbb{C} $ converges exactly then to $ x \in \mathbb{C} $ if for all subsequences
$ (x_{n_{k}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of
$ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ exists
an additional subsequence
$ (x_{n_{k_{l}}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of
$ (x_{n_{k}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $x$.

MY idea:
I assume that I have to look to this subsequence as sort of "composition of these" sequences. So I guess that I have to start to showing that $ (x_{n_{k_{l}}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of
$ (x_{n_{k}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$ and after that can I show that $ (x_{n_{k_{l}}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of
$ (x_{n_{k}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $x$. and the last step is $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $ \mathbb{C} $ converges. I'm still struggling to find a proof of it, anyway I'm not sure that my way of thinking is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to prove the contrapositive, which is equivalent: If $(x_n)_n$ does NOT converge to $x$, then there is an $\epsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ such that for all $k$, $|x_{n_k} - x| > \epsilon$. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot, but I still can't see exactly the proof

Comment: Let $(x_{n_{k_l}})$ be an arbitrary subsequence of the sequence I constructed. What can you say about that sub-subsequence ?

Comment: It herits the convergence or even the divergence of the original sequence.

Comment: So does it converge to $x$ ?

Comment: not because we are doing a contrapositive proof, so the original statement has to be negated. that means that $x$ diverges

Comment: "$x$ diverges" doesn't mean anything. Also, although we are assuming that $(x_n)_n$ doesn't converge to $x$, that does not in itself imply that the subsequence $(x_{n_{k_l}})$ does not converge to $x$. To prove that, we must use something about the intermediate subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Do you know the precise definition of convergence of a sequence to a limit ?

Comment: $ \forall \epsilon > 0( \exists N \in \mathbb{N}(n \ge N \implies|x_{n}-x|< \epsilon))) $

Comment: Ok good. I'm sorry but it's up to you now. You have to do a lot of thinking.